# Redmine - How to list all attachments in a project

Tags: plugins, issue-tracking, redmine, ticket-system

I was wondering if there is any way in [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) to get a list of all attachments with links to the respective tickets (or see only tickets that have an attachment).

I did not find any filter for this.
I did not find anything under the "Documents" or "Files" tabs.
I did not find a plug-in for this (should not be too hard to roll my own I guess).
I did not find anything googling or searching here on superuser.

Comment: Just searched Github for "redmine", quickly reviewed first 10 (of 31) pages, and nothing. Looks like you should dig deeper - or write your own plugin

Comment: Please accept my answer below if it is working for you, it's working for me now.

Comment: Sure thing, I did not try it in the end, but good to hear it's working for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a plugin called redmine_better_files, it does what you want plus some more:

- Issue attachments displayed on Files tab along with project files
- Global /files view shows all files available to the user

I haven't tried it though.
Download it from https://github.com/kulesa/redmine_better_files

Comment: I have confirmed that this plugin does not work for version 3.4.4-stable.  As of today (7 Feb 2018) it has not been updated for seven years.

Answer (score -1):

Look at the assets plugin. that might work.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please be a little bit more extensive in your answers. What's the Assets plugin? Where do I find it? How do I install it? How do I use it? How will it solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If you do mean [this plugin on GitHub](https://github.com/bshaffer/redmine-assets-plugin), it looks promising, but I don't see how I get from the asset to the issue (or Wiki entry etc.) it is attached to. Should be easy to patch though.